# Loading a Large Collection in a Meteor App

Tags: javascript, meteor

In a Meteor app, a large collection containing 1000 records is published to the client. However users loading the `{{loginButtons}` will experience a 3-5 second lag as it fully renders only after all the large collection loads.

It appears that the div `#login-buttons` rendered by `{{ loginButtons }}` is rendered instantly on page load, but **the div `#login-dropdown-list` is what's taking some time to start rendering.** [#login-dropodown-list template](https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/blob/d7cb70f358a8f57e020bc8a140098d11a8543120/login_buttons_dropdown.html#L5-L21)

The site is using Meteor 0.7.0.1 with Iron Router.

---

### Update

Here's the template code for the `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` dropdown menu that take a few seconds to load after the rest of the page renders. It's just the basic template from the Meteor package, nothing special.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    {{ loginButtons }} 
</ul>
```

I used to think the problem is due to that this dropdown menu using the `Meteor.users` collection, so here's my Fast Render route.

```
FastRender.onAllRoutes(function(urlPath) {
  this.subscribe(Meteor.users);
  this.subscribe(users);
})
```

This does not seem to help with the problem. I also found out that `Meteor.userId()` is already defined when the dropdown menu is still not rendered. The dropdown menu only appears/renders at the point in time pointed to by the red arrow, which is the point where all the collections have loaded.

Furthermore, the div `#login-buttons` rendered by `{{ loginButtons }}` is rendered instantly on page load, but **the div `#login-dropdown-list` is what's taking some time to start rendering.**

Maybe it's how `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` handles the rendering?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use iron-router's  `waiton` on specific routes and `loadingTemplate` properties to show the user a progress indicator while the subscription gets ready. As seen on https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#waiting-on-subscriptions-waiton

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('postShow', {
    path: '/posts/:_id',

    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('posts');
    }
  });
});
```

Also, https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/fast-render is a third party package which integates into iron-router and sends down the initial data along with the template therefore making the page appear loaded with data instantly.

There is a good tutorial about this at http://meteorhacks.com/integrating-iron-router-based-apps-with-fast-render.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I tried `fast-render` but the dropdown menu from the `bootstrap-3` package still takes some time to appear after the rest of the page renders. Is it because the dropdown menu is using the `Meteor.users` collection? Tried the following but it didn't help: `FastRender.onAllRoutes(function(urlPath) {
  this.subscribe(Meteor.users);
})`

Comment: what do you render in the dropdown? How do you initialize it? Can you post some code?

Comment: It's simply the template {{ loginButtons}} from the accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 Meteor package. The delay in rendering of the dropdown menu is also not due to not having received the `Meteor.user` as `Meteor.userId()` is defined before the dropdown menu is rendered. Updated the original post with the code. Maybe its how accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 handles its rendering?

Answer (score 0):

I see two other packages that could help you :

**Paginated subscription :** https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/paginated-subscription
The idea here would be to set a small limit for the initial load, and when the rest is loaded, change the limit to load the rest

**Lazy subscription :** https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/lazy-subscription
The idea here is not to subscribe at all to your large collection in the first time ; only init it like that :

Post = new Meteor.Lazy('post', function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('posts');
});

(it does not subscribe to anything)

And then when ready :
Template.some_template.get_posts = function() {
    return Post().find({}); //Note that Post is now a function.
};
=> it doe subscribe

The second solution may seem more straight forward, but you can manage it way better with the first one.