# Performance of large collection in Meteor 1.0.X

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

There has been a LOT of development in the Meteor world, and as such it's getting hard to find answers that work for current versions due to the plethora of answers you find for old, out-dated versions.

I have an app that has a LOT of data in a particular collection.  By lots I mean somewhere between 10k-100k, and very potentially a lot more.  Essentially it's log data, and I need to display the results in a table with no pagination (like a tail).  In researching ways to optimize large collections I keep running into things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886969/loading-a-large-collection-in-a-meteor-app) that seem to be for older versions of Meteor.

So, as I see it my options are:

- Use fast-render plugin to display the page prior to the subscription (at least this is my understand on how it works).
- Use some sort of progressive publish function, where it loads limited more relevant bits of data first, then progressively loads the remaining data by expanding the window/limit (not sure if this would cause heavier load on the server, though).  There seems to have been a "progressive publish" plugin, but it doesn't seem to be under active development any longer.
- Optimize the lookups via indexing (How do you specify that when creating the collection???)
- Profiling and optimizing the template further (not sure how).
- Some other method I haven't thought of yet...
- Some combination of all-the-above.

What is the proper approach by which to publish and render lots of data in this way?

Comment: Does all this data need to be reactive? If not then I would just skip Meteor DDP for this part. Just use a regular ajax call to get your data and render your table. Using Meteor DDP all that data would go into MiniMongo on the client then trying to keep 100k+ rows updated with the reactive data would probably be an issue on most clients regardless of how optimized the publish query was.

Indexing MongoDB:

http://joshowens.me/how-to-optimize-your-mongo-database-for-meteor-js/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/

Comment: The existing data would not change at all, but new documents would be added to the collection in real-time.  Is there a way to load part of the data statically, but the rest via DDP?  Maybe I could load the data then make a publication that says "Find only entries after this point"?

Comment: I didn't realize this before but reading the docs again I see the you can set a collection not to be reactive (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find), `collection.find({}, {reactive: false});` but I think it would still pull new records. Then with the query tuning / indexes it may work for you.

Comment: I tried turning off the reactivity on the collection, but this doesn't seem to help much.  Since my load times did not change at all, I did not pursue determining if new records still came in.  I am investigating what it will take to write something to split the load into two parts, a "reactive" part that allows new stuff to flow in, and a non-reactive part that simply reads the old data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that "optimize" means reduced query time.

Always start with the biggest bang for your buck. 
Unless you're publishing the entire collection, or query on the `_id`, then you want to create an index using `_ensureIndex`. Get more info on this on the mongodb website or by searching other questions. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/

Second, limit the fields to just the info you need. eg `{fields: {a:1, b:1}}`. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fieldspecifiers

Third, don't sort.

If this still isn't good enough, make another question with schema & query details & the desired UI so we can better understand the reactivity and why you can't use some form of pagination.